# use jest mock functions to test code that calls another server

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Roughly, my JavaScript function that I want to unit-test looks like this:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');
async function callServer() {
    // Prepare parameters
    // Call `request` with parameters
    // Parse response JSON and return
}
```

Is there any way to unit-test this function without making an actual call to the real server? Can I use a jest mock function to somehow override `request()`? To do that, will I need to modify every function to take the `request` function as a parameter or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock imported module via jest.mock. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#requirerequiremockmodulename

```
describe('main description', () => {
it('description of test case', () => {
    jest.mock('request-promise-native', () => {
        return {}; // Return what the request-promise-native supposed to return
    });
    const result = callServer(); 

    expect(result).toBe({});
});
});
```